# MYSQL calculation is returning a wrong value

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in my database. Column `r` and column `l`.
I have two rows in it. Row `302` and row `303`.

For row `302` I have the following data

```
---------------------------
|   k_id   |   l   |   r  |
|--------------------------
| 302      | 400   | 0    |
| 303      | 0     | 400  |
---------------------------
```

I am trying to run an SQL statement to select the total in row `l` and `l`.

In this case the calculation must be: `400 - 400 = 0`. But when I run the query I get `400` instead of `0`.

Does someone know why I dont get the right response?

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(l), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(r), 0) as total
FROM trans
WHERE user_id = '1' AND k_id IN ('302', '303')
GROUP BY k_id WITH ROLLUP LIMIT 0,1
```

Comment: why the `limit`?

Comment: Why use COALESCE. Why not just add up "l" and then subtract "r" from it?

Comment: I deleted the limit, Without the limit the response is three rows, First row: `400`, second row: `-400`, third row: `0`

Comment: The group by is the problem, you create multiple groups instead of one. Try `group by user_id`

Comment: Thanks, it worked @Matzi

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `group by k_id` part of the statement. This instructs mysql to do the sum by `k_id` values, therefore 302 and 303 will be summed up separately. Remove the `group by` clause and the rollup and you will get 0.